# Can I use camelCase with Laravel 4 eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have existing data in a mysql db whose columns are camelCased. I can't change them to snake case.

For instance: when I try to use "jobRole", I get "job_role". I want it to be "jobRole".

Is there a setting in laravel to support this? I've read about mutators but don't understand them. Is that the solution? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Discovered you can do this.

In the model, redefine "snakeAttributes" to "false" like this:

```
class YourModel extends Eloquent{
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was needed to make Accessors & Mutators work with camel case database column

Answer (score 2):

You can now. I've just completed a package that allows you to work with model attributes completely in camelCase, if required.

https://github.com/kirkbushell/eloquence

Install the package as per normal:

```
composer require kirkbushell/eloquence ~1.0
```

Then setup your service providers:

```
'KirkBushell\Eloquence\EloquenceServiceProvider',
```

Then all you need to do is either setup Eloquent to point to the new class as part of your aliases in application/config/app.php:

```
'Eloquent' => 'KirkBushell\Eloquence\Database\Model',
```

That ensures that the library is basically a drop-in replacement. If you want to just test with some models, you can simply extends the Eloquence base model class:

```
class MyModel extends \KirkBushell\Eloquence\Database\Model
```

I built this class mainly because I was sick of seeing snake_case in our javascript applications, but also in our server-side code. This ensured that everywhere (front-end and back-end) was dealing with camel casing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't I'm afraid. This bug: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/788 explains more but the long and short of it is that you need the field names to be all lowercase for the models to work.