# Laravel 5.3: Adding model method causing status code 500

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I have written a bunch of test cases for the registration form for a Laravel 5.3 project. One of the basic test cases is to insert fake data and check for the proper redirection. My test case code:

```
/**
 * Check for the registration form
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testNewUserRegister(){
  // Generate a ranom name
  $thisName = str_random(8);
  // Genearte a random email
  $thisEmail = str_random(8)."@google.com";

  // Type some valid values
  $this->visit('/register')
       ->type($thisName,'name')
       ->type($thisEmail,'email')
       ->type('password123','password')
       ->type('password123','password_confirmation')
       ->press('Register')
       ->seePageIs('/home');
}
```

Everything was working properly and no complaints from `PHPUnit`. But when I included the following method in my `User` model:

```
// Function to check for the adminship
public function isAdmin(){
  // Check if the user is logged in
  if(Auth::check()){
    // Check if the user is admin
    if(Auth::user()->isAdmin){
      return true;
    }
  }

  // Return false if not
  return false;
}
```

The above test case `testNewUserRegister` fails and following is the error message:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) AuthTest::testNewUserRegister
A request to [http://localhost/home] failed. Received status code [500].

/var/www/html/project-css/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:220
/var/www/html/project-css/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:92
/var/www/html/project-css/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:150
/var/www/html/project-css/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:92
/var/www/html/project-css/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:125
/var/www/html/project-css/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:580
/var/www/html/project-css/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:567
/var/www/html/project-css/tests/AuthTest.php:26

Caused by
ErrorException: Undefined property: App\User::$isAdmin in /var/www/html/project-css/app/User.php:36
```

Further, following is the database schema:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('isAdmin')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('hasAccess')->default(true);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Not a duplicate here is why:**

It's not due to the camel case as suggested. When included the following parameter the testing still fails:

```
public static $snakeAttributes = false;
```

Also modified the schema into camel case didn't solve my issue still the test fails.

Comment: Tell me what is clearer than this: `ErrorException: Undefined property: App\User::$isAdmin in /var/www/html/project-css/app/User.php:36`

Comment: @Kyslik there is a attribute `isAdmin` in the schema.

Comment: @PseudoAj Can you show us your schema?

Comment: Why don't you just go and do `dd(Auth::user())` and see yourself that its missing. FYI you should read something about middlewares and policies.

Comment: @ceejayoz Updated Schema

Comment: @PseudoAj I could be wrong, but I thought `$object->isSomething` looked for `is_something` in the DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use camelCase with Laravel 4 eloquent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584091/can-i-use-camelcase-with-laravel-4-eloquent)

Comment: @ceejayoz might be onto something

Comment: @ceejayoz did try changing the attribute; didn't work. Not due to camel case.

Comment: @PseudoAj Have you tried it with the modified schema as a test?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I did and doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

You can go about this 2 different ways.

**1. Change the migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(false);
    $table->boolean('has_access')->default(true);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**2. Create an Accessor**

In your `User` model create the following function:

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
    return $this->isAdmin;
}
```

This will just return the value of the `isAdmin` column in the database.

I would personally go with the first option, it's a better naming convention for tables and keeps everything organized.

Comment: did try changing schema into the camel case didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this: 
**In your User model:**

```
    public function isAdmin(){
    // this looks for an admin column in users table
    return $this->admin; 
}
```

**Now add an admin field to your database:**

> php artisan add_admin_to_users_table

**In your migration:**

```
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
       });
}


        public function down(){
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('admin');
    });
```

This should work properly.

Comment: I already have the admin in my migration. `$this` doesn't solved issue.

Comment: you are already in your User model, so you don't need to add the `check()` method. what i gave to you here, work very nicely my friend.

Comment: Agreed. But I believe and validated that the issue isn't with the check method. It is with the `isAdmin` property.

Comment: Did you try to do it like i wrote above? if not, then you will see it working. if you have the admin field, then don't add it, just replace you isAdmin function with my function. then you could use properly.